# WordPress - Reset Password - Redirect after providing email/username

Tags: wordpress, passwords

I am working on a website and on the password reset page, when a user provides a valid email/username, he gets redirected to `/login/?checkemail=confirm`. When a user provides a non-existing email/username, he gets redirected to `/lostpassword/wp-login.php?checkemail=confirm` which serves a 500 error.

I want both scenarios to redirect to `/login/?checkemail=confirm` but I cannot get it to work. When I apply the redirect via the htaccess file, it works but it isn't giving the result I need. I am trying to prevent user enumeration so I need both scenarios to do the same, except for sending the email. If I leave it with the htaccess redirect, a valid email/username redirects straight to the login page while a non-existing email/username is getting redirected to the wrong URL and then to the correct one. This will allow attackers to confirm which emails/usernames exist.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649497/wordpress-front-end-reset-password-page-redirect-after-username-or-email-doesn#answer-21654554) answer, but nothing happened. Any ideas?

Please let me know if more information is required.
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I am using a plugin called [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) and the website is multisite.

Comment: Are you using a plugin? cause /login is not a valid WordPress URL. Please provide a link to the plugin you're using to modify links. It'll be then easy to provide you with a working solution.

Comment: @VinayJain the plugin I am using is called `Theme My Login` and the website is multisite. I also added this to the question itself